# How to search a specific SD card and read from\write to it using Qt c++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, sd-card, device

I'm writing a desktop application in Qt IDE in C++ language, on Windows 7 OS.
I need my program to search in the computer devices list a SD card, named :"MY_CARD".
Only if this specific SD card is plugged - my program has to read the files in it, and to write to it new files.

I googled a lot, but didn't find any way how to do it.

Any idea?

thanks!

Comment: You googled for a ready-made solution to your **specific** problem. Instead, think of what *concepts* underlie your problem and are essential to it, *then* search for those concepts individually. For example, you want to detect device insertion and removal, and want to check the volume label of a drive.

Comment: ok, you were right. I googled again, now for the concepts underlie my issue, and found great solutions. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, guys, I found the solution. you should see the comment above... thanks!